# How to use PowerShell output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, powershell

I would like my JavaScript to use the PowerShell output, which is in JSON format, so I can draw a Google data table.

I have tried using `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` but it doesn't seem like the answer I'm looking for and for some reason `setTimeout()` isn't working anymore. I have also tried `event.dataTransfer.getData('Text')` but I received an error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getData' of undefined or null reference.

I kind of don't like having to copy to the clipboard because PowerShell does not take the same amount of time to finish executing every time. Additionally, the Google portion of the code constantly responds with error `Invalid JSON string` even though when I manually pasted the code, the data table loaded perfectly. I'm running on IE11.

Comment: How do you suppose to transfer data from a PowerShell session to a browser window? That's by impossible by definition (browser sandbox security).

Comment: I have tried using clipboard, so that when the powershell executes, it pipes the output to the clipboard, and then `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` will paste it into the javascript code.

Comment: Here's a proposal. It's a pretty standard situation. You need a webserver. Have a URL that executes your PowerShell script (or a bit of ASP.NET code) and returns the result. Use Ajax to retrieve it. Just about like everybody else does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a HTTP server (like Apache or Lighttpd) on your computer and dump your JSON output in a .json file in the HTTP server directory.

Then you can make an ajax HTTP request to retrieved the file everytime you need it.

Comment: That's how I wanted to do it, but the requirements say I can't create files

Comment: Does PowerShell is needed? Can you use another language?